# What is this recent movie about family secrets?

Tags: identify-this-movie

This should be easy for someone to remember.

It was possibly made in 2009-2010, set in an isolated seaside town in New York.
The wife thinks her husband is cheating on her but he's really taking acting classes and ashamed to admit it.

I thought the husband was De Niro, but I can't recognize the movie name in his filmography.

The parents thought the daughter was at college but she was stripping. The teenage son had a fetish for fat women. The wife went to cheat on her husband because she thought he was cheating on her.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The movie you are looking for is [City Island (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1174730/)

- The main actor is a corrections officer in the day and actor in private
- The daughter is supposed to be in college but she works as a stripper

The main actor reminds you of De Niro but you were thinking of [Andy Garcia](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000412/)